# I just built boost - and the output is sat on my desktop

Tags: boost, g++

I followed these instructions from github to clone and build the boost libraries.

https://github.com/boostorg/boost/wiki/Getting-Started

The end of the `./b2` command tells me

The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/user/Desktop/boost

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/user/Desktop/boost/stage/lib
```

What should I do with these folders? I would like to put boost in the "regular place it should go in order for gcc to see it".

This is probably `/usr/include` ? Is it safe for me to move the folder `boost` to this location? What about the `boost/stage/lib` folder. Where does this go?

```
gcc -v /dev/null -o /dev/null

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1) (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' '/dev/null' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cce2dq2i.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o /dev/null /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../.. /dev/null -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/dev/null: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to put boost in the "regular place it should go in order for gcc to see it".

For `gcc` run `cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null`. In its output there are include search directories and `LIBRARY_PATH` with a list of library search directories. These are the *regular places*. Copying the headers and libraries into the *regular places* normally requires `root` permissions.

Alternatively, use `-I/home/user/Desktop/boost` extra command line option when compiling and `-L/home/user/Desktop/boost/stage/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/Desktop/boost/stage/lib` when linking to use it from the current location.

---

Another way to build boost (and other 3rd-party libraries) is to have it installed in a separate directory, e.g. `/usr/local` with versioned directories, e.g. `/usr/local/boost-1.60.0`.

To build boost into `/usr/local/boost-1.60.0` do the following commands in `bash`:

```
$ cd boost-1.60.0 # The directory with boost sources.
$ JOBS=8
$ PREFIX=/usr/local/boost-1.60.0
$ mkdir -p ${PREFIX}
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=${PREFIX} --libdir=${PREFIX}/lib64
$ B2FLAGS="-j${JOBS} --layout=system --disable-icu variant=release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared linkflags=-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64 boost.locale.icu=off boost.locale.iconv=on"
$ ./b2 ${B2FLAGS}
$ ./b2 ${B2FLAGS} install
```

The `linkflags=-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64` bit makes sure that when you run your application boost shared libraries that depend on other boost shared libraries find them in that `${PREFIX}/lib64` directory.

And then use the following flags when builing your applications with boost you just built:

- Flags for compiling (`CPPFLAGS`): `-I/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/include`.
- Flags for linking (`LDFLAGS`): `-L/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/boost-1.60.0/lib64`.

Comment: The output doesn't tell me anything about where to put the `lib` directory?

Comment: @user3728501 Show the output (in your question).

Comment: @user3728501 In that output `LIBRARY_PATH`variable is a colon-separated list of directories where gcc looks for libraries when linking.